# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT chrome fix

Tags: google-chrome

So the issue is that i need to open this website and it isnt loading. The error appearing is the usual

This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

i can open the website on firefox but i do prefer chrome. what could be the fix for this. the website was working earlier but now it isnt.